# Java - trouble reading txt.file

Tags: java, text-files

I have created a method for reading a file in Java.  The file in question contains a list of books with the following format:  lastname|firstname|title.  However, when I try to use the method I get an error message.  My method is as follows:

```
private final static char END_SIGN = '|';

void readBookFile(String readFile) {
        try {
            FileReader textFileReader = new FileReader(readFile);
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(textFileReader);

            int numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++) {
                String post = textReader.readLine();

                int index1 = post.indexOf(END_SIGN);
                int index2 = post.indexOf(END_SIGN, index1 + 1);

                String lastname = post.substring(0, index1);
                String firstname = post.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
                String title = post.substring(index2 + 1);

                Book book = new Book(lastname, firstname, title);

                addBook(book);
            }

            tekstReader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.print("Wrong file reading: " + exception);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

When I try to run this method I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Twain|Mark|The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Library.readBookFile(Library.java:36)
    at LibraryTest.main(LibraryTest.java:8)
```

Line 36 is the part of the method where I identify the integer numberOfBooks.  So obviously this is not working for some reason.  If anyone knows what could cause this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: 5 answers within 60 seconds.   Wow.

Comment: Advice : never put any class in the default package. Always put your classes in a well-defined package (package com.yourcompany.yourproject.somepackage).

Comment: perhaps you would want to add the number of lines as its own line at the beginning?

Comment: Yes I know that I can add the number of lines as a separate variable, but since different files may have different number of lines, it would be nice if I could somehow automatically get the method to read the number of lines for the for-loop.

Comment: I didn't know there is a book about my adventures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this code:

```
int numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++) {
    String post = textReader.readLine();

    int index1 = post.indexOf(END_SIGN);
    int index2 = post.indexOf(END_SIGN, index1 + 1);

    String lastname = post.substring(0, index1);
    String firstname = post.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
    String title = post.substring(index2 + 1);

    Book book = new Book(lastname, firstname, title);

    addBook(book);
}
```

Try this:

```
String post = textReader.readLine();
while (post != null) {
    int index1 = post.indexOf(END_SIGN);
    int index2 = post.indexOf(END_SIGN, index1 + 1);

    String lastname = post.substring(0, index1);
    String firstname = post.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
    String title = post.substring(index2 + 1);

    Book book = new Book(lastname, firstname, title);

    addBook(book);
    post = textReader.readLine();
}
```

Also, like Jon Skeet suggests, you should rearrange your code to ensure that the input is closed even if the processing of the input throws an exception. (A `try ... finally` construct is good for this.)

Comment: beat me to it! solution instead of does not work is much more helpful++

Comment: Great!  This worked!  And thanks for the tip with the finally-construct.  However, now I seem to be getting a different error message later in my code.  Will try to fix it on my own though :).  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

```
int numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());
```

`readLine()` here returns the text of the first line of the text file.  That first line appears to be `Twain|Mark|The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn` and not a count of how many books are in the file.

What were you expecting the first line of the file to be?

Comment: Thanks.  You are right that the first line in the file is the Mark Twain book.  I see that this obviously would lead to a mistake now.  Do you by any chance know any tricks for how to get the method to read the number of lines in the txt.file?  I would want to avoid just typing in the number of lines in the for-loop since different files might have a different number of lines.

Comment: @Kristian I'd look at another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688431/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-out-how-many-non-empty-lines-are-in-a-file-usin

Comment: Alex : Thanks for the link!  Will look at it.  Appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 4):

Clearly the first line of your file *isn't* a number - it's the line that's being shown in the error message. You need to check your file.

A few other notes though:

- You should usually close your reader in a `finally` block
- You should almost *never* use the platform default encoding, which is all that `FileReader` supports, making it a mostly useless type. Instead, create a `FileInputStream`  and wrap it in an `InputStreamReader`, specifying the encoding.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) makes all of this easier with its `Files` class:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File(readFile), Charsets.UTF_8);
// All the IO is now done...
```

Comment: The only down side with using Guava like this is that the entire file needs to reside in memory at once. A streaming approach that processes a single line at a time can be much more space efficient.

Comment: @TedHopp True, in that case, Guava has `T Files.readLines(File, Charset charset, LineProcessor<T>)` :)

Answer (score 4):

The line you're reading in isn't a number.  It's the name of a book, so when it tries to read it as a number, it gives an error.  When you look at your input file, are you sure it begins with the number of lines to follow?

Comment: Thanks.  I see that this obviously would lead to a mistake now.  Do you by any chance know any tricks for how to get the method to read the number of lines in the txt.file?  I would want to avoid just typing in the number of lines in the for-loop since different files might have a different number of lines.

Comment: As the other answers have probably made clear, if a file doesn't tell you the number of lines, it's easier to just use a while loop to read the file until you run out of lines rather than using a for loop which requires knowing how many lines there are.

Comment: Yup.  This was really great help!  I am very grateful :)

Answer (score 2):

The code assumes the file starts with an integer, the number of books, alone on the first line. Apparently this is not present in your data file.

Answer (score 2):

The error already says it: You cannot create an Integer out of the String: "Twain|Mark|The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn": It's not a numeric expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
int numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());
```

the line that textReader.readLine() returns (the String) is not a number, since it returns:

```
"Twain|Mark|The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that "The file in question contains a list of books with the following format: lastname|firstname|title."

When before the for loop you try `int numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());` this throws an exception because it cannot convert a | separated string to an integer.

Assuming 1 book per line, the number of books is the total number of lines...